# Hosting Sub Domain In AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am new to AWS configurations, I have hosted a website in Aws Route 53,
in that I want to create a subdomain and sudomain is pointing to a Url cashlez.in/api I tried creating a CNAME record for that with Name as"api.cashlez.in" and Value as "cashlez.in/api" but I am getting Error Name Not Resolved Problem

Comment: Subdomains do not point to paths.  DNS does not work that way.  You point the subdomain to the web server, and the web server is responsible for the path mapping or redirection.

Comment: I have hosted apis in same server in another application in iis in this case what should i do